# SQL select individual data from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables User and booking

User

```
 Id    userphone
 1        11111111
 2        22222222
 3        33333333
```

Booking

```
 ID      bookingphone
  1       22222222
  2       11111111
  3       44444444
```

I want to get every individual phonenumbers from both tables
Like this:

```
 1111111
 2222222
 3333333
 4444444
```

How do I do this without getting duplicates? Only individual phonenumers as in my example

Comment: You can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` if you want to keep duplicates.

Comment: mysql, mssql, oracle or ... etc.

Comment: I do not want duplicates.

Comment: @Carson I am using mssql

Comment: @TorK, you can select User table and booking table into a temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT userphone FROM User
UNION
SELECT bookingphone FROM booking;
```

A `UNION` will, by default, remove duplicate phone numbers, which seems to be what you want to do.  If you want to retain all records from both sides, then replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

[`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
SELECT
  userphone
FROM user
UNION
SELECT
  bookingphone
FROM booking
```